# Is it possible to use a related field as a choice field in Django?

Tags: python, django

In Django, if I have something like this:

```py
class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    address = models.CharField(...)
    book_of_the_week = ?

class Book(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

This gives me the ability to create multiple libraries, each with a large number of books.

For `book_of_the_week`, I want this to be a reference to a Book instance, so that in Django Admin, the field is represented as a dropdown that lets you select from the books in the current library, and in code, you can use `.book_of_the_week` to access a specific instance of `Book`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would a `Book` need to know which library it is in?  I can understand a `Library` needing to know which `Books` it has, but not the other way around.

Comment: a better way would be just to create a class method where you return the ```book_of_the_week```. as only ```book_of_the_week``` doesn't look like something which should be in table of ```Library```

Comment: @shivankgtm The information about which book is the book of the week still needs to be stored somewhere (in the database), right? If that info isn't in the `Library` table, where else would it be for the method to retrieve? A method alone has no persistent memory.

Comment: @TimRoberts What do you mean? With the code above, you can access all books in a given library with `Library.objects.get(id=x).books...`. And sometimes, if you have a book object, you do need to know which library it's in, like if you want to drive to the library that has it to get the book.

Comment: probably just create a table called ```LibraryWeekBook``` and have two foreign keys of Library and Book. this way, you can be able to store each library best book of week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.  But if you do this, you'll only ever be able to save the *current* book of the week.  What happens if you want to show a library's book-of-the-week *history*?  Seems like a likely scenario to me. Consider doing something like:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    address = models.CharField(...)
    book_of_the_week = ?

class Book(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    name = models.CharField(...)

class BookOfTheWeek(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_of_the_week')
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, ...etc)
    week_of = models.DateField()
```

In this manner every book of the week will be a discrete database record, and you'll be able to track a history of each library's book of the week over time.

**However...**

That said, if you do not need to do this and a single instance record is fine, you should be able to create a ForeignKey relation from Library to Book.  However, you may run into some circular and/or hierarchical reference issues depending on how where your model classes are written.  In the example you show above, you'd need to declare your ForeignKey model name as a string, like so:

```
book_of_the_week = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete ... etc)
```

instead of:

```
book_of_the_week = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete ... etc)
```

...otherwise Django will throw an error because the Book model class is referenced before it is defined.  Making 'Book' a string will let Django parse the full models.py file, build the logic, and avoid the error.

**Sidenote:**

Depending on your specific case you may also consider a ForeignKey to self, like so:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
    name = models.CharField(...)
    book_of_the_week = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...etc)
```

This would allow any Book on the database table to reference another single Book instance.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but you're assuming my actual code deals with Libraries and Books. It doesn't. I don't need to track history. I just need to be able to have a field that is a reference to a single instance of the related objects. Your way, it makes it harder to access because each Library can have multiple `BookOfTheWeek` objects associated with it, when I will only ever have one. A single field reference would be simpler, if there's a simple way to do it

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'll update my answer with some additional info.

Comment: Now that I think about it, a `ForeignKey` reference like this would let you pick any book as a book of the week, even if it's not part of our library, but a different library. There's no way to limit the choices to only books in our library?

Comment: Within the django admin, I'm not sure.  It's certainly possible to limit the choices for your users if you're building the model forms yourself.